# Limiting input duration while increasing frame rate of a live stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm capturing a live stream and generating a sped-up output via adjusting the input-output framerates:

```
ffmpeg -r 1000 -i rtsp://url -r 60 -y output.mp4
```

This generates a sped up video as intended.

Now I want to capture only the initial 10 minutes **of the input** stream.

So I tried putting `-t 600` before the input:

```
ffmpeg -t 600 -r 1000 -i rtsp://url -r 60 -y output.mp4
```

But this creates a 10 min **output**.

Since this is (quite) a sped-up video, for a **10 min input** I'd expect the **output** to be **~<1 min**.

The input stream is variable frame-rate, so I'm not sure of the exact duration of the output.

What am I doing wrong?

- Does `-t 600` before input not tell ffmpeg to only take 10 mins of the ***input***?

  As Specified in the [FFMpeg Docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

  > - `-t duration` *(input/output)*
  >
  >   - When used as an **input option** (before -i),
  >
  >     - limit the duration of data read from the input file.
  >     - e.g. `ffmpeg` **`-t 5`** `-i input.mp3 testAsInput.mp3`
  >
  >       - Will stop writing automatically after 5 seconds
- Is it the manipulating framerate that's interfering with the above somehow?
- Is there any other way I can tell ffmpeg to only take 10 mins of the input (while still speeding up the output)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I should've been using the `setpts` filter rather than messing with framerates. This works:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://url -vf="setpts=PTS/100" -r 60 -y output.mp4
```